# Как мне исправить выпадаючие меню?

Tags: html, css

Я что-то делал, делал, но второе меню открывается не так как хочется. Оно открывается вниз, а мне нужно влево, как на рисунку снизу:
[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но получатся вот так:

[image]

[Код](https://codepen.io/indimops/pen/mdXBBgb)

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-logo">
            <a class="navbar-logo-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Indi Mops</a>
            <div class="navbar-links">
                <a class="navbar-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Главная</a>
                <a class="navbar-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Товары</a>
                <a class="navbar-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Каталог</a>
                <a class="navbar-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Доставка</a>
                <div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
                    <button class="dropbtn navbar-link">Меню</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <div class="dropleft">
                            <button class="dropbtn navbar-link">Язык</button>
                            <div class="dropleft-content">
                                <a href="/"><img class="flag" src="assets/flags/ru.svg"></a>
                                <a href="#"><img class="flag" src="assets/flags/us.svg"></a>
                            </div>
                            <button class="dropbtn navbar-link">Контакты</button>
                            <button class="dropbtn navbar-link">Еще меню</button>
                            <div class="dropleft-content">
                                <a href="#">Кнопка1</a>
                                <a href="#">Кнопка2</a>
                            </div>
                          <button class="dropbtn navbar-link">Еще пункт</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

--

```
.navbar {
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    font-size: 20px;
    display:flex;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-logo {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 30px
}

.navbar-links {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: inline;
}

.navbar-link {
    border-radius:6px;
    color:initial;
    font-size:1.25rem;
    padding:.5rem 1rem;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.navbar-link:hover {
    background-color:#3b3b3b;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.dropbtn {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: initial; 
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    min-width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius:6px;
    text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #5b5a5a;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
}

.dropleft {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    top: 5px;
}

.dropleft-lang {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 125px;
    button: 10px;
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    min-width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius:6px;
    text-align: right;
}

.dropleft-other {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 125px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    min-width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius:6px;
    text-align: right;
}

.dropleft-lang a {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropleft-other a {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropbtn:hover > .dropleft-lang {
  display: block;
}

.dropleft:hover .dropleft-lang .dropleft-other {
    display: block;
}

.dropleft:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(232, 231, 231);
}

body {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    font-family:  "SansDetect", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу Вам меню делать через список, вот пример. Это более простой и классический пример.

```css
.topmenu {
    display: flex;
    background: #000;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.topmenu > li {
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu > li > a {  
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FEFDFD;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.topmenu > li > a.active, 
.submenu a:hover {color: red;}
.topmenu .fa, 
.submenu .fa {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: inherit;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
  border-left: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transition: .3s linear;  
}

.submenu li {
    position: relative;
}
.submenu li a {
  color: #282828;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCC;
}
.submenu .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -101%;
  top: -1px;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

nav li:hover > .submenu {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="topmenu">
    
    <li><a href="">Тест</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тест</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Тест</a></li>

    <li><a href="">Меню<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">меню второго уровня</a></li>
        <li><a href="">меню второго уровня<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">меню третьего уровня</a></li>
            <li><a href="">меню третьего уровня</a></li>
            <li><a href="">меню третьего уровня</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">меню второго уровня</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я поседел денек над проектом и сделал все таки то что задумывал